# Call existing C++ code in electronjs

Tags: node.js-addon

I need to call an existing pure C++ code from ElectronJS with minimal changes in the C++ code.

I have used Node Addons to create wrapper but it uses v8 namespace and whole code needs to be modified.

Is there any way to call C++ code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is easier way to create addon [Native Abstractions for Node.js](https://github.com/nodejs/nan). But nevertheless you should change some parts. It can be tricky. But good luck!

**EDIT**
Found even simpler way to do it. Please, check [nbind](https://github.com/charto/nbind) much faster way to develop.

Comment: Thank you. I have used NAN to create Addons. It worked.